# PDO Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
```

In my table I did not have primary key with 0 and in `echo $item['nid']` no 0 value as well.

```
$insertTotalRes = $conWS->prepare('INSERT INTO totalresponses (nid, created) VALUES(:nid, :created) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nid = :nid , created = :created ');
$conWS->beginTransaction();
try{
    foreach ($output as $key=>$item){
    $insertTotalRes->bindParam(':nid', $item['nid']);
    $insertTotalRes->bindParam(':created', $item['created']);
    $insertTotalRes->execute();
    }
$conWS->commit();
}catch (PDOException $e){
    $conWS->rollback();
    echo "FAIL TO ADD ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}
```

But with this method i did not get the error.

```
$conWS->beginTransaction();
try{
    foreach ($output as $key=>$item){
    $insertTotalRes = $conWS->prepare('INSERT INTO totalresponses (nid, created) VALUES('.$item['nid'].', '.$item['created'].') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nid = '.$item['nid'].' , created = '.$item['created'].' ');
    $insertTotalRes->execute();
    }
$conWS->commit();
}catch (PDOException $e){
    $conWS->rollback();
    echo "FAIL TO ADD ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
}
```

I have no idea why, can anyone please tell me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how there's an error even though you have a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` construct, it would be likely the problem is in the `UPDATE` portion.

I noticed that you're reusing `:nid` twice; you will want to use a different alias for the second occurrence, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO totalresponses (nid, created) 
VALUES(:nid, :created) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nid = :nid2, created = :created ');
```

Then bind `:nid2` to `$item['nid']`.

From the [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) manual entry:

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.

Comment: @Eric You're welcome; btw, if an answer was helpful you can upvote it :) only saying this because from a couple of your earlier questions I've seen, the accepted answers mostly have zero score :)